# Splash Screen appear on resume despite using - finish() - before starting home Activity

Tags: android, splash-screen, onresume

In Android, I want to show Splash Screen only when the app is starting fresh and not when it is working on the background and resuming by the user.

So after reading here in Stackoverflow and over the web, I have added finish() before starting my home activity:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            finish();
            Intent appStarterIntent = new Intent(StarterActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            StarterActivity.this.startActivity(appStarterIntent);

        }
```

But Still when I (returning) opening the app from the background I see the Splash screen...
**How can I make the plash screen apprear only on fresh start of the app?**

Answer (score 0):

Save value 'isFreshStart' into SharedPreferences and start app only if there is no saved value. Remove this flag in onTerminate() method of Application class.
The point is, that Application instance gets destroyed when app is closed coimpletely, so you will know if it is a fresh start.